# How do I clear the blur of an element once clicked, and blur itself again after it being clicked again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, css-transitions, blur

So uh.. I'm trying to make a "unblur"/blur transition to a div element after it getting clicked, using the 2 class names in the following code: unblur and blur, which clear the blur / blur an element, respectively. Please take a look:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var n = false;
  var c = document.querySelector("#n");
  c.addEventListener("click", function() {
    n = !(n);
    $(".content").toggleClass(n ? "unblur" : "blur");
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  filter: blur(8px);
}

.unblur {
  filter: blur(0px);
  transition: filter 1s;
}

.unblur:active {
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(0px);
  transition: filter 1s;
}

.blur:active {
  filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="n">
  <div class="content">
    Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

However, something went wrong when the class "content" attempt to trigger the class "blur" after the "unblur" ones. How do I fix this? Thank you!!

Comment: `$(".content").toggleClass(n ? "unblur" : "blur");` you effectively have four states for the class of that element `.content`, `.content.blur`, `.content.unblur` and `.content.blur.unblur` .... perhaps now you'll see what went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

Revised Javascript in JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var c = document.querySelector("#n");
    c.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if($(".content").hasClass("blur")) {
            $(".content").removeClass("blur").addClass("unblur");
        } else {
            $(".content").removeClass("unblur").addClass("blur");
        }
    });
});
```

Updated CSS

```
 .content {
 width: 300px;
 border: solid 1px black;
 padding: 10px;
 filter: blur(8px);
 transition: filter 1s;
 }

.unblur {
  filter: blur(0px);
}

.blur:active {
  filter: blur(8px);
}
```

Comment: You have my thanks, sir. I understood how does my code works now! Thank you for fixing it for me.

Comment: Just FYI, but the 5 lines in your `if` statement can be replaced with just `$('.content').toggleClass('blur unblur')`